# Play specific local IPhone Video

Tags: iphone, video, alasset

I am in need for some help as I am stuck with a problem with my current IPhone application. I won't go into every details but the mainline is as follow:

I am currently playing videos from a remote URL. Everthing up to this point is working. But we need to add a certain validation as if the video exists on the local IPhone, play this version and otherwise, get the remote version. I get these informations from an XML feed and have the name of the video and it's remote URL.

I've implemented the ALAssetLibrary as a way to retrieve the locals video and transfered 3-4 videos with custom names. After some struggling, I could play these local video. But while I loop through them, all I get is names like 00001.jpg, etc.

Is there any way to get a local video name ? I don't mind if this needs another library but I would appreciate if someone could point me a way of doing it.

Thanks for your time,
AP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the local filenames, and even if you did those filenames would probably not be what you are expecting (i.e. Apple can and probably does rename them while saving them to the Camera Roll).

You can check the `metadata` on the `ALAssetRepresentation` for the video to see if a suitable name or other identifier can be found in there. You might also be able to retrieve the raw data and hash it, but that would fail if Apple does any recoding or metadata alteration when saving the video. If your program itself downloads and saves the videos to the Camera Roll using `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:`, you could store the returned `assetURL` to remember the correspondence. Or you could save the videos to your app's local storage instead of to the Camera Roll, but that would prevent the user from managing the videos with Apple's photo application and such.